# Chrome Extension with Firbease "URL violates Content Security Policy"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, manifest.json

Basically im doing a chrome extension with firebase, the auth works perfectly, but when I click the boton that triggers a post to the firebase db this error appears
[error csp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn5rZ.png)

The set function to db (Triggers on onClick): [function db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfH1R.png)

And this is my `manifest.json`:
[manifest.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykpn0.png)

Comment: Fix your content_security_policy as shown in the [official migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/intro/mv3-migration/#content-security-policy).

Comment: Please copy your code instead of uploading the image

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome Manifest version 3, you can’t load external scripts. You need to download all Firebase packages and include them in your extension package to be used with a service worker.

This video helped me: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=UjH2INUPmF4